# Navigation mode for audioItem

Tags: bixby

I would use the [audio sample capsule](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/audio) from Bixby developer centre to describe my situation.

I wish to create a **result-view** for playing audios. Let's say if the audioItem contain 3 audio info. When playing first audio, a page of **layout with details of the audio** will be shown, and after the first audio completed, it will **ask for user** whether they want to **go for the next audio**, if yes, the next audio will be played and details will be displayed too for the rest of the audio.

**What i Try**

By using the source code, I create result-view for it,

```
result-view{
  match{
    Result{
      from-output:PlayMeow{
        from-input:audioPlayer.AudioInfo(audios)
      }
    }
  }

  render{
    list-of (audios.audioItem){
      navigation-mode{
        read-one-and-next{
          page-content{
            next-item-question(next one?)
            overflow-statement(last one)
            underflow-statement(first one)
          }
          with-navigation-conversation-drivers
        }
      }
      where-each (item){
        title-area{
            slot2{
                paragraph{
                        style(Title_XS)
                        value("#{value(item.title)}")
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is not good,

- where i think the `next-item-question` should be the question asked
  **after** the audio played, but instead it asked **before** the audio played.

[image]

- For this example, the audio is too short to notice, but if you change to a longer duration of audio, when you pressed the **next button** underneath, the view will change to the next view, which is correct, but the playing audio (previous page audio) will continue to play after the new view dialog read out.

[image]

- And the main thing is the audio will not **stopped and ask** for user permission to continue, but it continue itself to play the next view, start from the dialog, followed by the audio.

Above is my try to achieve what i want, but the result seems not good, is there any other way, or improvement should i edit into the code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a feature that Bixby platform currently cannot support. Since capsule is unable to read the status of media player, developers cannot change the view after each track or provide more choice at the end of a track. The navigation command is for Hands-eyes-free mode only and cannot fulfill the challenge addressed here.

There is no callback or event handler once the media player is launched. Currently developers can re-launch media player with a new playlist or provide some command to media player such as resume/pause/next/previous using meta-command supported by marketplace. Might be easier for design purpose to treat audio player library as a one way communication at this moment.

You can submit a feature request using the IDE's contact support feature, or raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests%22%20target=%22_blank%22%20rel=%22noreferrer) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So for my case, if i still want to achieve similar effects, the only way is to `re-launch the media player with a new playlist` right? I checked for this and `replan` look like the way to do it as the situation look alike in some quiz example capsule. Is it possible to complete it by using `replan` associate with `navigation-mode`?

Comment: Relaunch a new playlist is certainly possible. I don't think `replan` is required (not sure the **fail** condition to trigger the `replan`), a normal continuation would get the job done in my mind. However, without callback event handler, the timing to prompt user would be tricky.